# Interact with bundle in Apache Felix

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-felix

I made a program that offers a CLI where you can type a number and calculate the square root of the number typed. I built a bundle starting from this simple application and installed on Apache Felix.
The problem is that I can't interact with it (insert a number in the gogo shell) when launched in Felix. Someone has an idea on how to solve this or a work-around to get it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can create listener on some port. Client will interact with your application using telnet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please add some details or links as I don't know a lot of this solution.